# Fetch DISTINCT records with JOIN of two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

**builders**

```
b_id fk_c_id
 1   1
 2   1
 3   1
 4   1
 5   1
 6   2
 7   2
```

**subbuilders**

```
fk_b_id sb_id
   1      2
   1      3
   1      4
   2      5
   6      7
```

and i want `Distinct b_id` which are not exist in **subbuilders** table and must have same **fk_c_id**

I create:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.id FROM pms_builder_to_subbuilders bsb 
LEFT JOIN pms_builders b ON b.id = bsb.sb_id WHERE b.fk_c_id = '1'
```

but it show Distinct records from **subbuilders**.

Comment: removed php5 tag, as this is applicable to mysql, no matter what programming language you use to access mysql

Comment: Can you rename your table and column names for example data to match your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b_ID
FROM builders
WHERE b_ID NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT fk_b_id FROM subbuilders)
```

but it returns

```
 b_ID
 ========
 3
 4
 5
 7
```

but i didn't understand your statement: `must have same fk_c_id`. What do you mean by that?

```
b_id = fk_c_id
```

if that's the case then there will be no rows returned because only record `1` has the same b_ID and fk_c_id but exists in table `subbuilders`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired results with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.b_id FROM builders b LEFT JOIN subbuilders sb ON sb.fk_b_id = b.b_id WHERE b.fk_c_id = '1' AND ISNULL(fk_b_id);
```